# How do I specify the path to the proxy file with the finished animation if the location of the rig has changed

Tags: animation, linked-data

I animated a character that was a proxy object. Then I transferred the scene file with the animation to another computer.

Now I need to use this animation, but I don't understand how to link the proxy file and the rig source. In Maya, this situation would look like this. I, in an animation scene that doesn't have a reference rig, set the path to that character. This is done in the reference editor.

But how do I do the same operation in Blender?
How do I specify the path to the proxy file with the finished animation if the location of the rig has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the outliner, open the Display Mode drop down menu and select Blender File:

[image: Display Mode]

This will make the Outliner display the content of the file, in terms of data. At the bottom of the list, you will find the linked data contained in your file.

From there, you can <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> a linked data, and relocate it from the contextual menu:

[image: Relocate]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Much obliged!

Comment: You welcome! Don't forget to mark this post as the answer and upvote :)

Comment: Sorry if I am doing something wrong in the forum. I'm from Russia, maybe some things are not translated correctly by chrome. Maybe you need to click "follow this answer to reseive notification"? I don't understand where to do "Don't forget to mark this post as reply and vote". I read in my profile that you have to mark replies and it adds reputation to those who help with advice. But the only buttons I have active are Share, Edit, Follow. I would appreciate advice on how to use the forum properly.

Comment: At the top left of every answer, you have buttons to upvote. And if it's an answer to your question, you have a checkmark icon ✔️ to set them as the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!